# How to create a 13 month moon based Calendar in .net

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, globalization, culture

hi i would like to create a custom calendar, this calendar will have custom month names and day names

it will contain
13 months with 28 days each

do i need to create and entire Culture or can i just created my own System.Globalization.Calendar implementaion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with .NET, but a quick googling turned this up.  Maybe you could use it as a starting point.

[Vietnamese Lunar Calendar for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/VnCalendar.aspx)